# Proof of existence of a specific subsequence in a given sequence

Tags: combinatorics

I recently came across the following problem in combinatorics:

In any permutation of blue and green dominoes, where the number of green dominoes is always $3n/5$ and the number of blue dominoes is $2n/5$ ($n$ is the total number of dominoes), it will always happen that there is at least one window of size 5 such that it contains 3 green dominoes and 2 blue dominoes, regardless of whichever permutation we consider.

For example, GGGGGGBBBB and GBGBGBGBGG contain GGGBB and BGBGG respectively. It has been found to be true by taking examples. I wish to give a formal proof of the same. Any help will be appreciated.

Note that $n$ is a multiple of 5.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g_i$ be the number of green dominoes in the window of 5 dominoes starting from the $i^{th}$ domino. You want $g_i = 3$ for some $i$. Obviously if $g_1 = 3$ you're done. Suppose that $g_1 > 3$. If $g_i > 3$ for all $i$, then every window of 5 dominoes contains at least $4$ green ones, and then the total number of green dominoes is $g_1 + g_6 + \cdots g_{n-4}$, which is at least $4n/5$. So you have $g_i \le 3$ for some $i$, and so $j := \min\{i : g_i \le 3\}$ exists, and is at least 2 since $g_1 > 3$. We now have $g_j \le 3$, and also $g_j \ge g_{j-1} - 1 \ge 4-1 = 3$.

The same argument works if $g_1 < 3$: you can't have every $g_i < 3$, and you know that $g_{i+1} \le g_i + 1$ for all $i$.

Comment: Well $g_{i+1}$ is equal to $g_i +1$ if the $i^{th}$ domino is blue and the $(i+5)^{th}$ is green, is equal to $g_i$ if they are the same colour, and is equal to $g_i - 1$ if the $i^{th}$ domino is green and the $(i+5)^{th}$ is blue. So $g_{i+1} \ge g_i -1$.

Now let $j = \max\{i : g_i \ge 4\}$. Then $g_{j+1} \le 3$ by definition of $j$, and $g_{j+1} \ge g_j - 1 \ge 4 - 1 = 3$, giving equality.